# Como contar valores repetidos dentro de um array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, vector

Estou aprendendo na marra JavaScript, porém me deparei com uma situação que não consegui resolver.
Estou querendo criar um gráfico onde A linha horizontal será a data (já consegui eliminar as datas que se repetem) e a linha vertical o número de vezes que ela se repete, por isso gostaria de saber como contar as datas que se repetem em sequência e jogar dentro de um array/vector.
Estou Utilizando o Firebase como meu banco de Dados.

Código:
 function tabela() {
    ref = Fire_input()

```
var coluna = []

ref.child("Tabela").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    dadosT = snapshot.key

    ref.child("Tabela").child(dadosT).on("value", function (snapshot) {

        dados = snapshot.val(); // Array completo 


        //CRIA O GRÁFICO

        coluna.push(dados.Data) // Array com todas as datas

        // ELIMINA AS DATAS REPETIDAS
        var novaColuna = coluna.filter(function (este, i) {
            return coluna.indexOf(este) === i;
        });

        // SOMA AS DATAS REPETIDAS
                ??????

 });

});
```

}

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Por exemplo: você quer a contagem de valores repetidos em sequência, ou a totalidade de repetições? Como você vai saber a que palavra o array retornado está se referindo? Não seria melhor retornar um objeto (hashtable/dicionário)? Elabore melhor.

Comment: Os repetidos estarão sempre em sequência?

Comment: Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    count: {
        value: function(value) {
            return this.filter(x => x==value).length;
        }
    }
});

arr.count("João") 
expected result: 4

Comment: para mim não importa se ele trará em sequência apenas contar os valores iguais que se repetem, mas se trouxer em sequência melhor ainda, agradeço.

Comment: @JeffsonOliveira, você pelo menos já tentou resolver esse problema? Por favor, clique em [edit] para adicionar o código que você tentou fazer...

Comment: Se o array for `["João", "Maria", "José", "João"]` qual deve ser o retorno? `[2, 1, 1]`? Ou João só conta 2 vezes se tiver mais de uma ocorrência seguida? Acho que foi isso que quiseram dizer quando perguntaram se os repetidos estão em sequência.

Comment: Blz vou Editar minha Pergunta inserindo o meu código.